# Proving SOR method convergence

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I would like to prove that the SOR method converges if $0<\omega\le 1$ and the matrix A (Ax=b) is row strictly diagonally dominant. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of the matrix of the process, I have that 
$$
|\lambda+\omega-1||a_{i_0i_0}|=\omega\sum_{j=i_0+1}^{n}|a_{i_0j}|+|\lambda|\omega\sum_{j=1}^{i_0-1}|a_{i_0j}|
$$
and I would like to prove that $|\lambda|<1$. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the standard SOR $(D+\omega L)x = \omega b -(\omega U + (1-\omega)D) x$?

Comment: Another ask & run...